# trying to insert data into a database using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, code-behind

I am trying to insert data into a table when a button on my asp.net page is clicked.  I don't get any errors, but when I try to redirect the user to a new page after the information is inserted, it stays on the same page.  Below is my code.

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
    db.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AboutYouEntities"].ConnectionString;
    db.Open();


    SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand insertContact = new SqlCommand();

    insertUser.CommandText = "INSERT into USER (Email, Name, Gender, BirthDate, LinuxDistro) VALUES ('" + userInfo.Email + "','" + userInfo.Name + "','" + userInfo.Gender + "','" + userInfo.BirthDate + "','" + userInfo.LinuxDistro + "')";


    insertContact.CommandText = "INSERT into CONTACT (Phone, Zip, Comments) VALUES ('" + userContact.Phone + "','" + userContact.Zip + "','" + userContact.Comments + "')";

    insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    insertContact.ExecuteNonQuery();

    db.Close();

    Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
```

Comment: Are u running this from a control (e.g. button click) which is inside of UpdatePanel?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Few problems with your code:

- You haven't attached connection with your commands.
- USER is [reserve word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and should be enclosed in square brackets like `[USER]`
- You should [parametrized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) your query, you are prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- Consider enclosing `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object in `using` statement as it will ensure disposal of the resources.

Code:

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection())
{
    db.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AboutYouEntities"].ConnectionString;
    db.Open();
    using (SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand())
    {
        insertUser.Connection = db;
        insertUser.CommandText = "INSERT into [USER] (Email, Name, Gender, BirthDate, LinuxDistro) VALUES (@Email, @Name, @Gender,@BirthDate, @LinuxDistro);";
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userInfo.Email);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", userInfo.Name);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", userInfo.Gender);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", userInfo.BirthDate);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LinuxDistro", userInfo.LinuxDistro);
        insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (SqlCommand insertContact = new SqlCommand())
    {
        insertContact.Connection = db;
        insertContact.CommandText = "INSERT into CONTACT (Phone, Zip, Comments) VALUES (@Phone, @Zip, @Comments);";
        insertContact.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", userContact.Phone);
        insertContact.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", userContact.Zip);
        insertContact.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", userContact.Comments);
        insertContact.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed my code around....I get no errors but it still doesn't go to the next page when the button is clicked.  If i take this code out, it redirects.

Comment: @user3255899, so this code is working ? you are probably getting an exception and it is holding up the code execution. Catch exception log it check it etc.

Comment: when i remove the block of code that adds it to the database, my button redirects the user but when I add in the code to insert into the database it does not work...ill try using catch

Comment: i got it to redirect, but it doesn't insert into the database...what can I do to check why